# In Docusign Envelope object Envelope Configuration Field is not populating from apex

Tags: docusignapi, apex, docusignapextoolkit

I am trying to send my opportunity record for docusign signature through apex, I would like to add some customised apex logic for which i need envelope template id, but its not populating under the object "Docusign Envelope" the value is null, but when i send for signature through the docusign created button the field is populated. Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Below is the apex code:

```
    mySourceId = '006S000000OARxxxxx'; // The ID of the initiating Salesforce object
    String templateId ='xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-ba3e7fe374a2'; // The ID of the DocuSign template

    // Create an empty envelope
    dfsle.Envelope myEnvelope = dfsle.EnvelopeService.getEmptyEnvelope(
    new dfsle.Entity(mySourceId));
    // The initiating Salesforce entity

    // Use myEnvelope for later 
    // We will use a Salesforce contact record as a Recipient here
    opportunity oppo = [select id,ownerid,owner.Name,owner.email,email_Custom__c,Name__Custom__cfrom opportunity where id =: mySourceId ];

    //use the Recipient.fromSource method to create the Recipient
    dfsle.Recipient myRecipient = dfsle.Recipient.fromSource(
        oppo.Name__Custom__c, // Recipient name
        oppo.email_Custom__c, // Recipient email
        null, // Optional phone number
        'Signer 1', // Role Name. Specify the exact role name from template
        new dfsle.Entity(oppo.Id)); // Source object for the recipient
    
            dfsle.Recipient myRecipient1 = dfsle.Recipient.fromSource(
        oppo.owner.name, // Recipient name
        oppo.owner.email, // Recipient email
        null, // Optional phone number
        'Signer 2', // Role Name. Specify the exact role name from template
        new dfsle.Entity(oppo.Id));
    

    // Add a recipient to the envelope
    myEnvelope = myEnvelope.withRecipients(new List<dfsle.Recipient> { myRecipient,myRecipient1 });

    // myTemplateId contains the DocuSign Id of the DocuSign Template
    dfsle.UUID myTemplateId = dfsle.UUID.parse(templateId);

    // create a new document for the Envelope
    dfsle.Document myDocument = dfsle.Document.fromTemplate(
        myTemplateId, // Template Id in dfsle.UUID format
        'EVSE Site Agreement Template1'); // Name of the template

    //add document to the envelope
    myEnvelope = myEnvelope.withDocuments(new List<dfsle.Document> { myDocument });

    // Send the envelope
    myEnvelope = dfsle.EnvelopeService.sendEnvelope(
        myEnvelope, // The envelope to send
        true); // True to send the envelope now
```

I tried creating new template and still the field didn't get populated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with your code. You would be able to find the envelope record in the DocuSign Apps Launcher > DocuSign Envelopes page. Since I couldn't find the envelope configuration field on the Details page of the envelope record, please give more detail on where you find the envelope configuration field.